# How to connect zend - laminas with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework, apache2, laminas

I am new to Zendlaminas and MongoDB.I know PHP. I want to connect the laminas with MongoDB. I do no from which file i need to start to config.For the whole day i am stuck here. Can anyone guide here.

1. I have installed Zend Laminas
2. Using a Apache2 server
3. Installed MongoDB as well
4. OS : Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [this](https://www.php.net/mongodb). I think there's a `php-mongodb` package for Ubuntu that will install PHP's MongoDb extension.

It might be overkill for your needs, but I suggest using [Doctrine ORM with MongoDB](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb-odm.html). There's a bit of a learning curve (ORMs in general are complex) but I find it a nice clean way to develop once it's set up.